# Trying to authenticate password stored in mysql with node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to authenticate password most of the tutorials i found are with mongodb but i have to do the same with mysql.Just to check if passwords stored in db and user provided password are same i am using compareSync and printing it on console but i see false everytime.

```
app.post('/register',function(req,res,next){
con.connect();
var username=req.body.username;
var passwordToSave = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password);
req.body.password=passwordToSave;
var values=[req.body.username,passwordToSave];
var post={USER_NAME : req.body.username, PASSWORD : passwordToSave};
console.log(passwordToSave);
con.query(insert_sql,post,function(err,result){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        res.json({message : "User successfully registered"});
    }
});

con.query('SELECT USER_NAME,PASSWORD FROM USERS WHERE USER_NAME =? ',username,function(err,result,fields){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log(result);
        var isPasswordCorrect = bcrypt.compareSync(passwordToSave, result[0].PASSWORD);
        console.log(isPasswordCorrect);
    }
});
```

Comment: You should test that you're saving the hash correctly, that it isn't trunacted. What is in your database for the password "testing"?

Comment: i have set the password field as varchar(100) in the database.

Comment: issue resolved i was passing the wrong argument to compareSync method

Comment: If it's that simple, might want to self-answer. Helps others in the same jam.